# How can I find an element with a class that has a text attrb but is not clickable within a main class that is clickable but has no text attrb

Tags: python, android, selenium, webdriver

I was trying to find a way to click on an element from a class/ID that has the clickable attribute TRUE but has no other attribute to be differentiated from the others.

The said element has another class/ID with the attribute text but has clickable is FALSE.

How can I do this using Selenium with Python?

How can I use 2 different classes to iterate based on the attribute text?

```
<Class/ID A (android.widget.RelativeLayout)/(com.project.ProjectName:id/itemContainer); 
           clickable: true; text: none;
           <Class/ID B (android.widget.TextView)/(com.project.ProjectName:id/title); 
                    clickable: false; text: BlaBlaBla>>
```

Here is the App source: [image]

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`Ancestors`**](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_nodes.asp) xpath:

```
//*[@text='BlaBlaBla']//ancestor::*[contains(@resource-id, 'itemContainer')]
```